# Document management solution for government IDs, insurance papers and other legal papers

Tags: document-management

I want to manage all my documents (such as bank statements, driving license, high school mark sheets, insurance certificates, etc.) through a software preferably via web interface with no software install.

I am looking for the following features:

- It should enable tagging
- Searching should be based on file contents and file name
- Version control for infinite time.
- **Preview** and editing of documents in pdf, jpg, docx, odt, xls format
- Possibly a file converter facility. For example, jpg image of X*Y (size 400KB) can be downloaded with image of size X' * Y' (size 100KB), or can be downloaded in pdf format with one click
- Grouping of documents can be don(besides tagging)
- Data should be kept in secure format
- Files can be shared via link
- An archive folder would be an A+

Comment: What is your budget? Alfresco can do this, with an hosted server costing about $20/month (open source software, hosted by various providers at various prices).